# angular 2 http post get bad request error

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am creating angular application to get data from laravel API,

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');
const loginInfo = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
return this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + '/api/v1/login', loginInfo, {headers: headers}).do((resp) => {
    if (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        localStorage.setItem(this.tokenKey, JSON.stringify(resp.json().access_token));
        console.log(localStorage);
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    return Observable.of(false);
});
```

this is the auth service I call from component to subscribe this method, but i keep getting "400 bad request". 
I also have tried to use

```
 loginInfo = new URLSearchParams();
 loginInfo.append('email', email);
 loginInfo.append('password', password);
```

or using form-data content type. but all return me same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
urlSearchParams.append('email', email);
let loginInfo = urlSearchParams.toString();
```

.toString() the parameters

Comment: i have tried it before, same error
POST http://homestead.app/api/v1/login 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Have you used your network tab in developer tools to track the http request? Also is the route setup correctly on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const loginInfo = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
let body = JSON.stringify(loginInfo);
return this.http.post(this.ApiUrl + '/api/v1/login', body,{headers:headers}).do((resp) => {
```